# foreach syntax in csh

Tags: linux, shell, csh

For this `csh` script

```
#!/bin/csh

foreach file in (.)
  echo "$file"
end
```

I get this error

```
foreach: Words not parenthesized.
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Avoid csh, especially for scripts: http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/ Use `zsh` if `bash` or Posix `sh` is not good enough for you.

Comment: so what is the equivalent in bash?

Comment: http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/

Comment: Bash equivalent is `for file in .; do echo $file; done`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There should be no `in`:

```
foreach file ( . )
```

Be sure to read [Stop Using (and Teaching) C-Shell](http://www.shlomifish.org/open-source/anti/csh/).

Comment: FYI, some people may be forced to use CSH due to vendor hardware - as in the case of ASML equipment, for example. ( https://wiki.nanotech.ucsb.edu/wiki/Stepper_3_(ASML_DUV) )  Installing new shells (or installing anything in general) is not recommended on such equipment to ensure functionality is not compromised.  I do entirely agree though - I wish I could use something other than CSH!

Answer (score 0):

I found that csh was giving me issues splitting the files into their own iteration of `$file` (it would lump all the files into a single string with EOL's in between! Go figure...), so I had to use the following explicit call to `ls`:

```
foreach file ( `ls /path/to/directory/` )
    echo "/path/to/directory/$file"
end
```